# Pause-Resume Audio on button click

Tags: java, android

Hi Guys i create a audio play button that plays audio i named as "a" here found in the raw folder   ...everything is working well the audio is being played when pressing the Play button,but i need to pause the audio on another button,also i need to add resume  ....i tried but my try  failed and no way it can work,,if you know any code to do that please support me and thanks

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int resId;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Play:
            resId = R.raw.a;
            break;

        default:
            resId = R.raw.a;
            break;
    }
    // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
    }
    // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `switch` statement when your `resId` is always `R.raw.a`?

Comment: i had another button that plays another audio but i removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `MediaPlayer` object `mp` a class variable. And use the following code to stop/pause/resume the `MediaPlayer` playback

```
MediaPlayer mp;
int length;

//Inside constructor write this code
{
int resId = R.raw.a;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
}//End of Constructor



public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.play:
      mp.start();
      break;

    case R.id.pause:
    mp.pause();
    length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
    break;

   case R.id.resume:
     if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
     mp.seekTo(length);
     mp.start();
     }
     break;

   case R.id.stop:
    mp.stop();
    break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check now, I've modified the answer.

Comment: The problem was, we are creating the `MediaPlayer` instance newly everytime the button click is happening, so to avoid that instantiate the `MediaPlayer` object in the constructor. Please check my modified code.

Comment: Force Close when app opens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79490/discussion-between-prince-and-mrad4tech).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation link -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

From This link -

> Playback can be paused and stopped, and the current playback position
>   can be adjusted. Playback can be paused via pause(). When the call to
>   pause() returns, the MediaPlayer object enters the Paused state. Note
>   that the transition from the Started state to the Paused state and
>   vice versa happens asynchronously in the player engine. It may take
>   some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying(), and it
>   can be a number of seconds in the case of streamed content.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to release the MediaPlayer and create a new one? For stop, pause and resume, you can call `mp.stop()`, `mp.pause()` and `mp.start()`. Probably, you only need create MediaPlayer in `onCreate()` and call `mp.release()` in `onDestroy()`.